# "Device in editor" list is empty

Tags: android-studio

Following some annoying glitches, I decided to invalidate caches and restart. Now, my layout editor is broken: nothing is rendered, and the device list is empty (and the API version drop down simply says "<null>"). Further invalidate & restarts or removing the .idea folder do nothing.

The version is Android Studio 3.1.2, specifically. I've included a screenshot to show what is (not) happening.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

"Sync Project with Gradle files" did the trick. Naturally, after an hour or two of looking for solutions, the solution appears two minutes after posting the question.